# Why is my wireless network adapter acting in a strange way? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, 14.04, power-management

I have a laptop with Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 wireless network card, and I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. For almost a week I have had a strange problem with my wireless card. When I plug in the power cable, the network card stays connected to the access point, but stops receiving altogether, but works completely normal on battery.

From the little digging around, I was narrow it down as a power management related issue. By design when I'm running the laptop on battery, the wireless card is in power management:on status, as verified by `sudo iwconfig` command. When I plug in the power cable, it goes into power management:off status, and stops receiving. Upon manipulating it with `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power on`, while still connected to the AC power, the power management is turned on, and the card starts to function normally.

The same laptop does not have this trouble when booted in Windows 7, so I don't think it is an OS independent case of faulty component. Is there a sophisticated solution to it, or do I need to rely on some shoddy script to execute `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power on`, every time I plug in the power cable?

Answer (score 1):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless.bak
gksudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless
```

When the file opens, make the following changes; I refer to the line number in the file on my 14.04 system:

```
Line 38: iwconfig_ac="power on" instead of off
Line 41: *) iwconfig_ac="power on" instead of off
Line 75: false) wireless_powersave on ;; instead of off
```

Spacing, spelling, etc. are crucial so proofread carefully. Save and close gedit. Reboot and check:

```
iwconfig
```

If this is unclear, I have posted my amended file here for reference: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8020443/

On my 14.04 system, after reboot, power management is on for both AC and battery.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but that didn't keep the power management on, when I plugged in the power cable.

Comment: $ lsmod | grep iwl   

iwldvm                232285  0   

mac80211              626489  1 iwldvm  

iwlwifi               169932  1 iwldvm  

cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get proper formatting on that output paste.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: sorry for a late reply. I made the changes as you have suggested above. But that does not keep the power-saving on after connecting the power supply.

Comment: May I proofread your file? Please post it here and give me the link. http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: here it is.. http://pastebin.com/i6zbf43T

Comment: Sorry, I have no other suggestions. The method works perfectly on my iwlwifi-driven system.